# how to go down dynamicaly in UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, uilabel, trace

I successfully display UILabel inside a UIScrollView,
but how to skip/jump/go to end of the text dynamicaly ?
My code is as following and work perfect.
Which code I have to add to jump to the end of the text ?
is it possible ?
I try to reproduce an effect of log/trace...
Thanks
Fred

```
-(void) log:(NSString *)msg
{
    // alocate and initialize scroll
    UIScrollView *myScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f)];
    // alocate and initialize label
    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f)];

    myLabel.text = msg; //a long text 

    // set line break mode to word wrap
    myLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    // set number of lines to zero
    myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    // resize label
    [myLabel sizeToFit];

    // set scroll view size
    myScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myScroll.contentSize.width, myLabel.frame.size.height);
    // add myLabel
    [myScroll addSubview:myLabel];
    // add scroll view to main view
    [self.view addSubview:myScroll];
    // release label and scroll view

    [myLabel release];
    [myScroll release];
}
```

Comment: Dear just set ContentOffset of that ScrollView

Comment: @user1164417 Please mark any of the answers as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with setting contentOffset for the UIScrollView

Check this : [setContentOffset:animated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setContentOffset` method of `UIScrollView` to scroll, like :

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```